# VBA Histogram showing error "Bin Range cannot be Empty" with 1 row of data

Tags: excel, vba, histogram

I'm trying to create a VBA macro that produces a bunch of Histograms on Excel using the Analysis Toolpak Add-in. things seem to be going pretty well, the only issue I'm facing is if there's only 1 row of Data, Excel throws up an error saying "Bin Range Cannot be Empty". If there's 2 or more rows of data there's no issue.

Could someone tell me how I can fix this or if there's a workaround I can use?

Comment: Are you asking how to create the chart with only a single row of data or how to skip datasets that only contain one row?

Comment: Create a chart with only single row of data